# Sending Queries to SQL Server once added to server explorer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual Studio 2013 Professional and Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I have my server found in Visual Studios and created a Data Connection to it so it shows up in my Server Explorer (see image below). However I can't find the server to add to my SQLConnection function. I am creating the project in Asp.net 4.5 Web Application using Visual C#. On Button2 click I get

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
 but was not handled in user code
 Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not
 conform to specification starting at index 0.`
```

Code

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("jason.Delta.dbo");
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into account (UserName, Password,FirstName, LastName) Values(@user, @pass, @first, last)");
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", UserName);
```

[image: Server Explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide the full connection string to your database.

e.g

```
"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I couldn't get user id to work so I opened it up as a trusted_connection so I don't need a user name and password and since this is only running on my machine it doesn't create a security problem.